# Recoil: Triggering a function on atom change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, recoiljs

I'm trying to store a user object inside an atom and have it be cached inside `localStorage` each time it changes because the app might crash and I do not want the user to have to sign in every time:

```js
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
```

Previously when I used `useContext` this was achieved through a `useEffect` in the parent component (App.js) that monitored the `user` object for changes. It's no longer possible for me to do this after migrating from `useContext` to `Recoil` due to my NextJS project structure (`RecoilRoot` wraps around the children component, so the parent `App.js` itself does not have access to `useRecoil` methods). And so, I'm wondering if there's a way to implement this kind of listener or callback using a built-in Recoil method

Desired process:

1. Declare the state: `const [user, setUser] = useRecoilState(userAtom)`
2. Trigger a change `setUser({...})`
3. Trigger a callback on state change `localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))`

---

Solution: There's a built-in `effects` hook in the `atom()` constructor

Docs: https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/atom-effects/
(Refer to 'Logging Example')

```js
export const userAtom = atom({
    key: 'user',
    default: null,
    effects: [
        ({onSet}) => {
            onSet(data => {
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data))
                console.log("Updated User Data (state.tsx): ", data)
            })
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `useEffect` hook, which lets you do something extra when your atom state changes. You can get the current value of your atom state with the `useRecoilValue` hook, and then pass it as a dependency to `useEffect`. Inside `useEffect`, you can save the `user` object in `localStorage` so you don't lose it. For example:

```
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";

const userAtom = atom({
  key: "userAtom",
  default: null,
});

const userValue = useRecoilValue(userAtom);

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userValue));
}, [userValue]);
```

Comment: Doesn't work - `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')` and the error points at the line where you declare `const userValue = useRecoilValue(userAtom)`

Comment: Did you wrap your component with RecoilRoot Provider?

Comment: I have my state in a separate `state.js` file and pasted your code in that. The `state.js` file itself just stores all the atom code and does not return any functional components so it is not wrapped inside a RecoilRoot provider

Comment: The error is expected because my code should be in the component. If so, where do you use `localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userValue));`?

Comment: I found a solution - there's a built-in `effects` in `atom()`:
`export const userAtom = atom({ key: 'user', default: null, effects: [ ({onSet}) => { onSet(data => { localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data)) console.log("Updated User Data (state.tsx): ", data) }) } ] })`